# Python Tuple & List Manipulation (As an input to the SVM model in scikit-learn)

Tags: python-2.7, scikit-learn, svm

I have a list that looks like this:

```
[[(0, 0.17), (7, 0.87), (84, 0.04)]
 [(0, 0.11), (3, 0.01)]
 [(33, 0.56), (81, 0.22), (96, 0.04), (99, 0.97)]
 ...
 ...]
```

Every tuple is of the form (index, weight), where index ranges from 0 to 99, and weight takes on values in (0, 1].

What I want to do is fill the missing indexes of every list with 0 weight, and remove the indexes:

Original:

```
[(0, 0.17), (7, 0.87), (84, 0.04)]
```

Transformed:

```
[0.17, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.87, ..., 0.04, ..., 0]
```

Does anyone know any simple way to do this?

Also, is this the best way to input features to the SVM model in scikit-learn?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's quite easy to do so with `dict`s and list comprehension.

Say you have originally

```
>>> orig = dict([(0, 0.17), (7, 0.87), (84, 0.04)])
```

And the list's logical size is 100.

Just do

```
>>> [0 if i not in orig else orig[i] for i in range(100)]
```

---

If you're planning on manipulating this further for `sklearn`-related matters (e.g., SVM), I suggest you then transform it into a `numpy.array`:

```
>>> w = np.array([0 if i not in orig else orig[i] for i in range(100)])
```

Comment: Hi, I have another question. Is it possible to simply turn my original list of lists to a sparse matrix and use it as the input to the SVM model? It takes forever to add those zeros... .

Comment: Yes. If you have a specific question about it, though, I suggest you start a separate, unrelated, question. The site is not really built for a dialog through the comments.